# Retrieve data from API using Java

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

How to retrieve data from API and store it in a mobile database? Java is preferred. I just started into this, and consider me a beginner.

Comment: Break the problem down.  You are asking about too many different things.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and ensure you had created API client server to retrieve and read your data :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get data from API

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "app_key=whatever");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://app.inyek.com/app_api/api_extra/all_order.php")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("key", "whatever")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("Postman-Token", "whatever")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

And use the below `activity` to store api data into `sqlite`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    // creating variables for our edittext, button and dbhandler
    private EditText courseNameEdt, courseTracksEdt, courseDurationEdt, courseDescriptionEdt;
    private Button addCourseBtn;
    private DBHandler dbHandler;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        // initializing all our variables.
        courseNameEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCourseName);
        courseTracksEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCourseTracks);
        courseDurationEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCourseDuration);
        courseDescriptionEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCourseDescription);
        addCourseBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnAddCourse);
         
        // creating a new dbhandler class
        // and passing our context to it.
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
         
        // below line is to add on click listener for our add course button.
        addCourseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 
                // below line is to get data from all edit text fields.
                String courseName = courseNameEdt.getText().toString();
                String courseTracks = courseTracksEdt.getText().toString();
                String courseDuration = courseDurationEdt.getText().toString();
                String courseDescription = courseDescriptionEdt.getText().toString();
                
                // validating if the text fields are empty or not.
                if (courseName.isEmpty() && courseTracks.isEmpty() && courseDuration.isEmpty() && courseDescription.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter all the data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                 
                // on below line we are calling a method to add new
                // course to sqlite data and pass all our values to it.
                dbHandler.addNewCourse(courseName, courseDuration, courseDescription, courseTracks);
                 
                // after adding the data we are displaying a toast message.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Course has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                courseNameEdt.setText("");
                courseDurationEdt.setText("");
                courseTracksEdt.setText("");
                courseDescriptionEdt.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```